# After logging in using AngularFireAuth, I call getUser and that returns undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire2

I am using Angular in an Ionic 4 project, with Firebase and Firestore Database. I have the following code in AuthService and AuthGuard:

```js
// auth.service.ts

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<ProUserInfo>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        console.log("SET USER REACHED USER", user)
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }));
  }

  getUser() {
    console.log("GET USER REACHED")

    return this.user$.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  }

  async emailAndPasswordSignIn(usercreds: UserCreds) {
    const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(usercreds.email, usercreds.password)
      .then(async (res) => {
      // console.log("CALL SET USER")
      // await this.setUser();
      return res;
    })
    .then(
      res => resolve(res),
      err => reject(err));
    });

    return promise;
  }
}
```

```js
// auth.guard.ts:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.authState
      .pipe(
           map(authState => !!authState),
           tap(auth => !auth ? console.log('Access Denied!') : true),
           take(1)
       );
  }
}
```

I then have the following code in my login page:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage {
  credentials = {} as UserCreds;
  errorMessage = '';
  uerrorMessage = 'Email or Password Incorrect';

  constructor(private router: Router, public authservice: AuthService,
              public ppi: PrivateProInfoService, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
}

  async signin() {
    const toaster =  await this.toastCtrl.create({
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom'
    });

    await this.authservice.emailAndPasswordSignIn(this.credentials).then(async (res: any) => {
        console.log("Login Page response", res);
      })
      .catch(async err => {
            let msg;
  
            switch (err.code) { // SWITCH THE CODE RETURNED TO SEE WHAT MESSAGE YOU'LL DISPLAY
              case 'auth/wrong-password':
                msg = 'Email or Password is wrong.';
                const toast1 = await this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: msg,
                  duration: 2000
                });
                toast1.present();
                alert(msg);
                break;

              case 'auth/user-not-found':
                msg = 'User not found.';
                const toast2 = await this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: msg,
                  duration: 2000
                });
                toast2.present();
                alert(msg);
                break;

              case 'auth/invalid-email':
                msg = 'Email or Password is wrong.';
                const toast3 = await this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: msg,
                  duration: 2000
                });
                toast3.present();
                alert(msg);
                break;
            }

            alert(msg);

          });


        const myUser = await this.authservice.getUser();

        console.log("myUser", myUser);

}
```

That final console.log statement is returning undefined, which is problematic because that getUser function is then used for lookups in the database. I am fairly certain this may be caused by things getting instantiated out of order, but I awaited emailAndPasswordSignIn, which should mean that I can retrieve my auth information in getUser, but this is not the case as the call comes back undefined.

The purpose of all this is to sign in, then immediately get the user info with getUser, do a lookup in my Firestore Database for where my user should be routed to, and then take the result and then route them to the next page based on that database value. This is failing because getUser is returning undefined.

This same auth service was working before I started this immediate lookup. I think that I just wasn't running into this problem before because I would log in, that would take me to the next page, and on that next page I would perform a database lookup of some sort. In the time it took to get to that next page, my auth info was probably finalized, so I was not seeing this previously.

Ideally, I would like to wait until the user is not undefined from getUser, before looking up info based on the result.

Comment: I would guess that your initial state is not logged in, so `this.user$.pipe(first()).toPromise()` emits `undefined`.  You can try filtering out `undefined` values like this `this.user$.pipe(filter(u => !!u).toPromise()` to see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried this.user$.pipe(filter(u => !!u)).toPromise(); along with this.user$.pipe(filter(u => !!u), first()).toPromise();  both did not work

Comment: This is really dumb, but I had a typo in the uid I was using in my /users table, so when my app went to fetch the info it found nothing and came back undefined, as you would expect.